Mount USB stick and make it available for all users of specific group
I created a directory /mnt/pendrive and made the directory available to the group pendrivegrp:
$ ls -lh
drwxrwxr-x 2 root pendrivegrp 4.0K Apr  5 16:43 pendrive

All the users from pendrivegrp can read and write to /mnt/pendrive, ok. Now I want to mount a USB stick, formatted in FAT32, to /mnt/pendrive and keep the same behavior, i.e. that all users from pendrivegrp can do whatever they want there. How can I do this?
If I do sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/pendrive then the group ownership of /mnt/pendrive changes to root:
$ ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan  1  1970 pendrive

and it does not let me to change it, not even with sudo. As soon as I ummount it, things are reverted.
If I mount it with sudo mount -o gid=1001 /dev/sda /mnt/pendrive now ls -lh shows a somewhat better output,
$ ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root pendrivegrp 4.0K Jan  1  1970 pendrive

but still the permissions are not enough. I have even tried sudo chmod 770 /mnt/pendrive and the command does not seem to do anything, no error, no changes.

Does this answer your question? Mount USB drive (FAT32) so all users can write to it You will need to modify the umask to allow only group access. You might also check out this question.

So the whole issue is coming from the fact that it is FAT?

Correct. You're trying to use features that the file system itself does not support. If you re-format the pendrive with NTFS you will have better luck and it will still be usable on a Windows/Mac desktop.
